# Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource: spring boot 2.4.1

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, java-ee-6

I get this output will running me spring app

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

    Property: driver-class-name
    Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
    Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

my pom.xml look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>couponProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>couponProject-Spring </name>
<description>coupon project part 2 spring</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

and my application.properties looking like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/couponproject?serverTimezone=Israel&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I'm new to spring so I don't really understand why I get this output
I used spring initializer spring JPA
I read similar questions but I couldn't quite understand the solution

Comment: Please give MySQL driver dependency and  execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is not able to find the jar because maven dependency is missing for MYSQL Drivers . Please add below dependency for mySQL 8 in order to get the drivers available for your application . Add it inside the `<dependencies>` section of your pom.xml .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you want to have another 8.X or 5.X version MySQL based dependency (based upon which version of MySQL it is that you are using) , please use the correct maven dependency from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java .